# TFLite + NNAPI on ARM board breaks when a new thread is started

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite, imx8

I have a NXP board equipped with a NPU where a python script for image processing is executed. The script acquires images and process them using Tensorflow Lite and NNAPI delegate. In particular I have [tensorflow-imx](https://github.com/nxp-imx/tensorflow-imx) installed with YOCTO.

The TFLite interpreter is initialized and invoked in the main process. I noticed that when I start a thread that uses subprocess to perform some operations on the filesystem, this breaks the tflite interpreter which starts providing always the same output. The following script shows the problem by randomly loading images and processing them. A thread is periodically started and this causes the problem. What could be the reason for this?

```
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread
from random import random, choice, randint
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
import time
import cv2 
import os
import sys
import psutil
import subprocess

class ClassificationModel(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.model_path = path
        self.interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=path)
        self.interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        self.input_details = self.interpreter.get_input_details()
        self.output_details = self.interpreter.get_output_details()
        self.input_shape = self.input_details[0]['shape']


    def predict(self, img, resize=True):

        if resize:
            img = cv2.resize(img, (self.input_shape[2], self.input_shape[1]))   


        img = (img/255.0).astype(np.float32)

        img = np.expand_dims(img, 0)
        t1 = time.time()
        self.interpreter.set_tensor(self.input_details[0]['index'], img)                
        self.interpreter.invoke()           
        output = self.interpreter.get_tensor(self.output_details[0]['index'])
        output = np.squeeze(output)
        
        return output

    def reload(self):
        del(self.interpreter)
        self.interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=self.model_path)
        self.interpreter.allocate_tensors()

        

def my_thread_1():
    print("Start threaded task 1")
    # copy one large file
    for i in range(5):
        subprocess.Popen(["cp", "f1/file.txt", "f2"])
    
            
    print("Task 1 completed")

    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    classifier_1 = ClassificationModel('model.tflite')
    file_list = os.listdir('samples')
    prev_pred = 0
    n_equal = 0

    try:
        while True:                 
            # get image
            img1 = cv2.imread(os.path.join('samples', choice(file_list)))
            
            # predict           
            p1 = classifier_1.predict(img1)[0]
            print(p1)
            

            if p1 == prev_pred:
                n_equal += 1
            else:
                n_equal = 0

            prev_pred = p1
            if n_equal == 10:
                print("--------tflite broken - reload")
                classifier_1.reload()
                n_equal = 0
        
            # threaded task
            if random() < 0.05:
                t = Thread(target=my_thread_1)
                t.start()
    
    except(KeyboardInterrupt):
        pass
```